# Loading data once the data is in array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

```
[array addObject:textdata.text];        

NSUserDefaults *save = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[save setObject:array forKey:@"success" ];

[save synchronize];

-(void) viewDidLoad

NSUserDefaults *viewdata1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[viewdata1 objectForKey:@"success"];

[viewdata1 synchronize];

[tabledata reloadData];
```

Once the data is saved in the array, how do I upload it once the app runs again? I want the data to load back in the table once.

Comment: Do not call `synchronize` when you read data from `NSUserDefaults`. It's not really necessary to call it when you update data either. The only reason to call `synchronize` at all is to ensure critical data is saved if the app crashes before the data is automatically synchronized by the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to retrieve it from user defaults. The second step is not to drop it on the floor.

```
[viewdata1 objectForKey:@"success"];
```

This does one, but not the other: You retrieve it, but then you drop it on the floor.

You need to store the object as the value of a property (which means you will need to declare a property for that purpose), then, in your table view's data source, return the count of that array as your number of rows and objects in the array (or properties of those objects) as the row values.

Also, you shouldn't need to call `synchronize`, especially *after* retrieving the value.

Answer (score 0):

You should make like this:

TSTableViewController.h:

```
@property(nonatomic, readwrite, retain) NSMutableArray* dataSource;
```

TSTableViewController.m:

```
- (id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:)
                                                     name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                                   object: nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: self.dataSource
                                              forKey: @"success" ];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray* array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"success"];

    if (array)
    {
        self.dataSource = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: array];
    }
    else
    {
        self.dataSource = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
    }

    [tableView reloadData];

}
- (void) addDataToDataSource
{
    [self.dataSource addObject: textdata.text];
    [tabledata reloadData];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [dataSource release];
    dataSource = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: when implementing your code, it is giving me a warning "local declaration of "array" hides instance variable. Any idea why?

Comment: you have as instance variable with name array. You must rename array to other name.

Comment: It's misleading to name the array property `dataSource` when it's the table view controller that's the data source. Also, this assumes that the questioner is targeting iOS.